# Links won't open in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Whenever I try to open a link posted in teams chat it'll launch browser & try to load https://teams.microsoft.com/multi-window/?agent=web&version=21101905016 link instead of the original link I'm trying to reach. Already tried removing %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams folder but no luck.

However, if I copy the link using right click "Copy Link" and paste in browser then it works.

Any suggestions? TIA.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft I didn't find a solution but don't see that anymore with the new version of teams I installed. Will post if came across this issue again.